# Get a row number on select statement while matching entire row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a row number of the row. Since the table doesn't have any id column, I have used `ROW_NUMBER()` without any order which is shown below.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SNO, * 
FROM [table1]
```

Now the challenge is i need to find a row with a condition which is just a select statement with where clause but with a original row number.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM table1 
WHERE [Total Sales] = 2555
```

This statement returns a single record. I have tried to use `INTERSECT` to combine both statements to get result with row number.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS SNO, * 
FROM [table1] 

INTERSECT 

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table1
WHERE [Total Sales] = 2555
```

Of course, this throws errors since number of columns are different. So what is the correct way to get the actual row number ?

Comment: You have to specify an existing column in the `ORDER BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`, otherwise the row number returned for each row is undetermined and may vary from one query to another.

Comment: Yeah, but i want row number on table as it is, it should not be ordered.

Comment: There is no "actual row number" so the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run this query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SNO, t.*
FROM [table1] t;
```

The `SNO` values are *unstable*.  That means that the same query run multiple times might return different numbers.  Sorting in SQL is not *stable*.  That means that identical keys can be in an arbitrary order when the query is run multiple times.  Why?  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is nothing to base a stable sort on.

The simplistic answer to your question is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SNO, t.*
      FROM [table1] t
     ) t
WHERE [Total Sales] = 2555;
```

However, the real answer is that you should be using multiple columns to create a stable sort, if you want to use this value for more than one query.

Comment: above query works! I know that row number without order will get results with different numbers. But i need to maintain the order of table as it is and i can not add identity column as these tables are created dynamically and will affect other components. Is there better way to do this ?

Comment: @suds - In what sense do you believe this query works? It gives you the row numbering allocated using the access path the query optimizer decided to use. This is not at all guaranteed to correlate to anything such as insertion order.

Comment: The query might appear to work because he's seeing the incidental sort order of the clustered index. Although SQL Server doesn't guarentee a sort order in a case like this, it will usually use the order in the clustered index. In which case it's better to do an ORDER BY over the fields in the clustered index/ primary key

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not have an initial "row number" for the entries. The table order shown is all based on the query results. If you are looking to keep them in the order they are put into the DB then maybe add a time stamp that's generated with a trigger and attached to the row when it's inserted. Then using this times tamp you can have them sorted by that.

What's the primary key if there is no I'd?